# PHP mkdir not working as expected

Tags: php, web, syntax, mkdir

I'm working on some PHP that will create a folder every time a request is made to my server.  I can't seem to get my syntax proper. If I just used the $date variable it works no problem, however when I add the "clean" folder before it, it won't create the folder.

```
<?php

$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$date =  date(Ymd_Hms, $time);
$new =  "clean/".$date;

echo $new;

if(!is_dir ($new))
{
    mkdir($new);
}

?>
```

Comment: have you created folder `clean` on your server.?

Comment: Have you tried Ymd_Hms in quotes?

Comment: You probably want `His`, not `Hms`.

Comment: @Barmar What does `His` does instead? Shed some light please?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari `H` means hour, `i` means minute, `s` means second.

Comment: Well, unless you have "clean" folder in place, mkdir won't create 2 nested folders for you without "recursive" flag (3d parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the in `'` quotes and give the mkdir() appropriate params and it should work fine:

```
<?php
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$date =  date('Ymd_His', $time);
$new =  "clean/".$date;

echo $new;

if(!is_dir ($new))
{
mkdir($new, 0777, true);
}
?>
```

mode:
    The mode is `0777` by default, which means the widest possible access. For more information on modes, read the details on the [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

> Note: mode is ignored on Windows.

Return Values:

> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.
>
> Note: You don't have to create the folder `clean` first *IF*  you're using the `recursive = true` option, Otherwise a folder named `clean` must be created first.

[PHP Manual: mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

> PS. I've created a directory using this code before posting so it should not
>   have any problem.

Comment: Second `m` by the way will still be `month` and not `minutes`.

Comment: The `mkdir` arguments are optional.

Comment: you should explain what 0777,true does, I believe this may actually solve the problem if clean didn't exist

Comment: If you leave out the quotes around an identier, and it doesn't name a defined constant, PHP will treat it as a literal string.

Comment: This was to the best of my knowledge about it. If there is anything I am missing please tell me? As its always better _to learn and help_ than _to downvote and leave_ right? `:-)`

Comment: Since you're using the `recursive = true` option, he doesn't have to create the `clean` folder first. Recursive means it will create all the intermediate directories.

Comment: I swear I tried with ' and not ", but I must have been mistaken.  But it's working now, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelAhrendt Ahh, I am glad it worked out for you. I learned somethings as well. Stay safe and keep coding `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

This is scenario is happened to me when I recently configure server
mkdir() function was working and it was giving permission error constantly.
So I found out the solution that folder (in this case clean folder) in which you are creating another folder must have 0777 / 0755 permission and its user:group must be same as that of user and group given in httpd.conf file in apache or httpd folder .

`chown -R root:root clean/`
when I gave that to that folder it was working like magic.
   Please check with this , if all above solutions failed then this will definitely help you.